# How to insert dynamic blocks of html inside SendGrid email?

Tags: html, email, sendmail, sendgrid

I'm using SendGrid web API v3. Trying to generate personalization object which includes many recipients. Each recipient has 1 email with data that related to current recipient (pass with substitutions)

**Example:**

```
personalizations: [{
       to: [{email: 'example@mail.com'}],
       subject: 'Hello, :name!',
       substitutions: {':name': 'John', ':info_section_html':'<p>Some useful block1</p><p>Some useful block2</p>'}
    },
    {
       to: [{email: 'example@mail.com'}],
       subject: 'Hello, :name!',
       substitutions: {':name': 'John', ':info_section_html':'<p>Some useful block1</p><p>Some useful block2</p><p>Some useful block3</p><p>Some useful block4</p><p>Some useful block5</p><p>Some useful block6</p>'}
    }
],
    from: {email: 'send@example.com'},
    content: [{type: 'text/html', value: 'Hello, :name! </br> Here are your very usefull info</br> :info_section_html'}]
```

When substitution: `info_section_html` has a lot of such blocks it crossed a limit of 10000 bytes. My blocks have a lot more HTML than in example. Each recipient can have a different number of blocks that's why I can't include them in content attribute.

Also was thinking about sections attribute where I can pass HTML of my `info_section_html`. But can't pass array of data in substitution.

Can someone please suggest how to overcome this?

Answer (score 2):

I know this comes quite late, but I was facing the same issue and couldn't find the answer so I'd figured that maybe it would be useful to still post it here:

As can be found here: [SendGrid API v3](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/api_v3.html)

*A collection of key/value pairs following the pattern "substitution_tag":"value to substitute". All are assumed to be strings. These substitutions will apply to the text and html content of the body of your email, in addition to the subject and reply-to parameters. The total collective size of your substitutions may not exceed 10,000 bytes per personalization object.*

So there's nothing to do about it here.

For this usage Sendgrid has another feature called **Sections** (check link above as well). They work almost like `Substitutions` except that they're are link to the whole mail and not per `Substitution`

They can be used together with `Substitutions` to achieve behavior like stated above.

As said by **mbernier** here: [Github issue related to the topic](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/301)

You can use them like this:

```
    "personalizations: [
{
    "to: [{"email":"bob@example.com"}],
    "substitutions": {
        "[%product_info%]": "[%has_product%]",
    },
},
{
    "to":[{"email":"bob@example.com"}],
    "substitutions": {
        "[%product_info%]": "[%no_product%]",
    },
}],
"content": [
{
    "type": "text/plain",
    "value": "We just wanted to tell you that we appreciate you being a long time customer! [%product info%]"
}],
"sections": {
    "[%has_product%]": "Also, thanks for ordering:<br />[%product_section%].<br /> Are you ready to order again!?",
    "[%no_product%]": "You haven't ordered in a while, but we'd love it if you came back and saw our new products!"
}
```

Most important here is that the sections should be added via a substitution tag.

Hope this helps